# Google Apps Scripts: Is there a way to write an Array of values from a single cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Kind of like how you can do so in just plain Google Sheets.

So if I have an array [1,2,3], is there a way I can say to GAS "From cell A1, write in values [1,2,3] to cells A1:C3". If I had an array of say [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], then arrays [1,2,3], [4,5,6], and [7,8,9] would be written to rows A1:A3, B1:B3, and C1:C3, respectively.

I know I can define the range to which I want to write in the values by the way, and that this would work, however, this would not be viable if the range to write into the sheet changes in size.

Comment: *however, this would not be viable if the range to write into the sheet changes in size.* It is viable. You can get dynamic range as shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create a custom function with overflow

E.g.

```
function overflow(){
  var values = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
  return values;
}
```

And then type into cell `A1`: `=overflow()`

If you want to do it from the Apps Script instead of the Sheets UI, you need to write the function as following:

```
function overflow2(){
  var values = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
  //for cell "A1":
  var startRow = 1;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, startColumn, values.length, values[0].length);
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helps ^_^